# SQL query with quotes doesn't return results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to query my sql database using PDO. There are instances in which there are quotes in my query.

```
function getPageByPagid($pagid) {
    $db = dbConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pagid='".$pagid."'";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $q->execute();
    $results = $q->fetch();

    return $results;
}
```

The function I'm using does prepare my SQL so that it still should work if $pagid has quotes in it. Now it is working when there aren't quotes, but it still isn't when there are quotes. Why isn't this working?

P.S.: The quotes aren't escaped or anything in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be causing you have integer type of field and sending string try with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pagid='$pagid'";
```

or better to use placeholder (PDO standard)

```
function getPageByPagid($pagid) {
    $db = dbConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pagid= :pagid";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindParam(':pagid', $pagid);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $q->execute();
    $results = $q->fetch();
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: The latter should work, although the former should be exactly the same as the query in the question, no?